# creating port pin's Array in Hi-tech C

Tags: pic, c, microchip, hi-tech-compiler

I am using pic16f887 microcontroller and using Hi-tech C compiler. I want to implement port pin's Array in Hi-tech but it is not allowing me to do so. 
What is the correct way to access pin address with indexing, like we do in arduino.

i want array like

```
   bit * lcd[4]={RA0,RA1,RB0,RC4};
```

it gives following errors

- arrays of bits or pointers to bit are illegal
- constant expression required
- illegal conversion of integer to pointer

It clearly means I cannot declare Arrays of Bit, what is the other way to access pin numbers via indexing in standard C style or any other compiler related trick.

In header files pins are declared in following manners

```
    // Register: TRISB
    volatile unsigned char           TRISB               @ 0x086;
// bit and bitfield definitions
volatile bit TRISB0              @ ((unsigned)&TRISB*8)+0;
volatile bit TRISB1              @ ((unsigned)&TRISB*8)+1;
volatile bit TRISB2              @ ((unsigned)&TRISB*8)+2;
volatile bit TRISB3              @ ((unsigned)&TRISB*8)+3;
volatile bit TRISB4              @ ((unsigned)&TRISB*8)+4;
volatile bit TRISB5              @ ((unsigned)&TRISB*8)+5;
volatile bit TRISB6              @ ((unsigned)&TRISB*8)+6;
```

My problem is that, I do not want to name the port I want to index them so that I could call them with their numbers like we do in arduino style

```
 digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
```

Comment: You need to write a function that takes a pin number and produces a port name and pin number (or equivalent register and bit). Look at the source code of `digitalWrite()`.

Comment: In AVR the individual pin is not accessible, mean AVR C is not bit adressable, but the PIC is. Once I got the port name (let say, PORTA); and i got the pin number 1, then I have to read and write that port via logical and or OR. I want some way of bit adressing. Is there any way in Hi-tech or I have to tackle this problem with writing a bit in byte with logical opertions?

Comment: The individual pins _are_ accessible, using the port and pin number and logical operators. Again, the source code of `digitalWrite()` has all of this, and it should be trivial to port this to Hi-tech C.